# CNTK load pictures with class affiliation in percent

Tags: deep-learning, cntk, map-files, mini-batch

I am trying to build a neuronal network with CNTK to estimate the age of a person.

Currently I want to try an approach using only one class. So every picture gets label 0 but also an affiliation to the class in percent. 
So the net should learn that the probability of a 30 year old person to match class 0 is 30% ... 60yo = 60% ... 93yo = 93%.

Currently I am working on a reduced data set of 50k images (.jpg) and use the [MiniBatchSourceFromData](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.io.html?highlight=minibatchsourcefromdata#cntk.io.MinibatchSourceFromData) function.

Since I have a lot more training data available (400k + augmentations) I wanted to load the pictures in chunks for training, due to limited server RAM.
Following [THIS](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html) CNTK tutorial I have to use the [MiniBatchSource](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.io.html?highlight=minibatchsource#cntk.io.MinibatchSource) function and feed a deserializer with a map_file which includes the paths and labels to my training data. .

My Problem is, that the [map_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/brainscript-image-reader#crop-transform) doesn't support class affiliations. I can only define what picture belongs to which class.

Since I am new to CNTK and deep learning in general, I'd like to know if there is another option to read chunked data as well as tell the network how likely it is that the picture corresponds to  a specific class.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composite reader. One deserializes you images, another can deserialise your numeric data.

[Read this, the last section shows you how to use a composite reader](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html)